# Is it possible to access clones in other functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, clone

I have a function called taskButtonClick() that:

1. Sets the variable form to a clone.
2. Sets the variable formParent to the outer most div.
3. removes a parents div and it's elements.
4. and replaces those removed elements with the form.

   ```
   function taskButtonClick() {
   $(".task-btn").click(function(){
       // Setting form to the clone I want to acces in .on()
       var form = $(this).closest('#form-to-date').clone(true);
       var formParent = $(this).closest('#date-container');
       $(this).closest('#form-to-date').remove();
           $(formParent).html('\
               <form>\
                   <fieldset>\
                   <legend>Task<button class="btn task-btn" id="exit- button"><img src="http://localhost/ia/assets/img/remove.png"></button></legend>\
                    <input type="text" class="span12 input-xlarge"  id="input01">\
                   <div class="control-group">\
                       <div class="controls">\
                       </div>\
                   </div>\
                   <div class="form-actions">\
                       <button class="btn btn-primary span12"  type="submit">Save changes</button>\
                   </div>\
                   </fieldset>\
               </form>\
               ');
   });
   }
   ```

There's an exit button added with the form which I've created a .on() function for and attached a click handler. I'm trying to figure out a way to access the variable form(the clone) from within the .on function and replace the form with the previous content:

```
$("#date-container").on("click", "#exit-button", function(event){
alert("Exit Button Works.");
event.preventDefault();
    // Here's kind of what I'm going for
$(form).appendTo(formParent);
});
```

I'm not very familiar with jquery so please let me know if I can somehow better clarify.

```
Edit: Here's where I'm calling the funcitons:

$('document').ready(function(){
    setAjax();
    initialize();
    setDates();
    setButton(); 
    setActiveNav(); 
    taskButtonClick();
    removeButtonClicked();
});
```

Comment: Why do you have the .task-btn click event inside a function?

Comment: @MikeGB Probably because I'm doing something wrong. The way I've been writing my jquery is to create the `$(document).ready(function(){})` and in between those brackets, call all of the functions.

Comment: Your method may work but it's not needed. The event will be executed when clicked, you should not have to call the function to fire the event. It should still be inside $(document).ready(function(){}) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring a global variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       //Notice variable is outside of the event function. It can be accessed by other functions and events.
       var formParent = null;

       $(".task-btn").click(function(){
    // Setting form to the clone I want to acces in .on()
    var form = $(this).closest('#form-to-date').clone(true);
    formParent = $(this).closest('#date-container');
    $(this).closest('#form-to-date').remove();
        $(formParent).html('\
            <form>\
                <fieldset>\
                <legend>Task<button class="btn task-btn" id="exit- button"><img src="http://localhost/ia/assets/img/remove.png"></button></legend>\
                 <input type="text" class="span12 input-xlarge"  id="input01">\
                <div class="control-group">\
                    <div class="controls">\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
                <div class="form-actions">\
                    <button class="btn btn-primary span12"  type="submit">Save changes</button>\
                </div>\
                </fieldset>\
            </form>\
            ');
     });
});
```

Comment: The only reason I didn't try this approach initially is because I've heard that it's not a good idea to use global. Is this the exception?

Comment: The only difference is the data will be still available to the application. A local variable (inside a function) will be cleared once the processes have finished.

Global variables aren't "bad", they just linger. This is desired though for your use as you want to access the variable globally inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the clone variable, use a global variable declaration.